# Cannot read properties of null (reading 'getContext')

Tags: javascript, null

I get this error message:

> "Cannot read properties of null (reading 'getContext')".

Why?

```js
let canvas = document.getElementById("gameSecreen");
let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.fillRect(20, 20, 100, 100);
```

```css
#gameScreen {
   border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="gameScreen" width="800" height="600"> </canvas>
```

Comment: `document.getElementById("gameSecreen");` you have typo `gameScreen` instead of `gameSecreen`

Answer (score 0):

The error is pretty self explanatory. "Cannot read propery getContext of null" means the object on which you're calling the function `getContext` is null

`let canvas = document.getElementById("gameSecreen");` here canvas is null because in your HTML the id of the canvas is `greenScreen` but you used "greenSecreen" inside getElementById.

```js
let canvas = document.getElementById("gameScreen");
let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.fillRect(20, 20, 100, 100);
```

```css
#gameScreen {
   border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="gameScreen" width="800" height="600"> </canvas>
```

Comment: Thanks. So it was a typo. Sorry, Im new to this. Will check my code better before I ask another question. THANK YOU!

Comment: no problem happens to anyone :)